# Is there a nice way, in Python, to measure the number of memory accesses, or mems, used by a function?

Tags: python, memory, time-complexity, knuth, mems

When people ask about memory, they're often asking how much memory is being used, but this is *not* what I mean.

Rather, I'm reading through Donald Knuth's The Art of Computer Programming, and recreating some of the algorithms in Python. Knuth measures the time it took one of his programs to run in [mems](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mem_(computing)), meaning the number of times an area of memory was read from or written to. This is a nice way to measure the time an algorithm takes as an exact number that is more independent of chip architecture or speed.

As an example of what I'm looking for, consider this example script:

```
mylist = [1, 2, 3]
x = 2
y = mylist[x]
```

You might say there are 5 mems here, like this:

```
mylist = [1, 2, 3]  # Write to `mylist`. 1 mem
x = 2               # Write to `x`.      1 mem
y = mylist[x]       # Read from `x`, `mylist`; write to `y`. 3 mems
```

You could also argue that the assignment to `mylist` ought to count as multiple writes because it represents more memory usage than a single value.

Right now I'm just trying to solve the high-level problem of having *some* (any) way to reasonably measure mems, ideally without having to do any fancy magic-looking coding :) Later on, I may start to worry more about details like "what is the best way," or "how many mems should this line count as," but this question is focused on "what is the first way to begin doing this?"

And I do mean programmatically, as in, I run a function, and somewhere in Python is a variable which has kept track of the number of mems used as the function's been run. (As opposed to, say, a human statically analyzing the program to get a count, or manually adding `n += 1` for every memory access.)

Comment: That's an interesting metric for assembly language, where you have exposure to the low-level operations.  It's not meaningful for a language like Python.  That first statement accesses many, many memory locations.  It has to create 3 integer objects, create a list object, add the integers to that list, then bind the name `mylist` to that list object.  Would you count `x = 2` differently from `x = y`?

Comment: You seem to be implying that this is a pointless question that cannot possibly have a meaningful answer. I politely disagree because, for example, we can stick to basic Python usage (which is my use case), and simply ask how many times we make an assignment or retrieve what Python sees as a single value. In other words, I'm explicitly saying "make practical assumptions / restrictions so that some version is possible."

Comment: But Python doesn't have "single values".  The statement `x = 2` in Python does not store 2 in memory cell `x`, like it does in C or assembler.  Instead, it binds the name `x` to the integer object `2`.  Similarly, if I write `y = x`, that doesn't read a `2` from `x` and write it to `y`.  It just bind the name `y` to whatever object was already bound to `x`.  The concepts are too different -- the metric is not meaningful.

Comment: Multilevel caches have access times in the range 0.5 ns L1 cache to maybe 100 ns main mem,
see [Latency Numbers Every Programmer Should Know](https://gist.github.com/jboner/2841832)
(but: unknown machine, unknown variance in the numbers).
Given that huge range, I don't see how to define a "mem" that can predict runtimes even in C, let alone Python.
Has anyone run code from Knuth's GraphBase lately ?

Answer (score 0):

I don't really know of a nice way of doing this, but I think it would actually go against Knuth's original recommendation. In The Stanford GraphBase, he declared

```
#define o mems++
#define oo mems += 2
#define ooo mems += 3
```

and then proceeded to manually add those macros, for instance

```
...
o, a->from = v;
oo, a->klink = aucket[l];
...
```

His reasons for doing so were

> (1) The macros can be inserted easily and quickly using a text editor. (2) An implementation need not pay for mems that could be avoided by a suitable optimizing compiler or by making the C program text slightly more complex; thus, authors can use their good judgment to keep programs more readable than if the code were overly hand-optimized. (3) The programmer should be able to see exactly where mems are being charged, as an aid to bottleneck elimination. Occurrences of o and oo make this plain without messing up the program text. (4) An implementation need not be charged for mems that merely provide diagnostic output, or mems that do redundant computations just to double-check the validity of "proven" assertions as a program is being tested.

---

Regarding the point that "the metric is not meaningful" because Python is not like C or Assembly, note that Knuth proposed this to compare algorithms in terms of *memory references*. So even if Python deals with pointers, this can still be a helpful comparison between competing implementations.